# Can I sort my divs according to classes using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 divs

```
<div class="row events-list-section employee-hour-detail-section 11-28-2017">
</div>
<div class="row events-list-section employee-hour-detail-section 11-27-2017">
</div>
```

The divs have common classes employee-hour-detail-section and date as extra class.

I want to sort these divs according to date. How can I achieve that? I want the output to be sorted date wise.

```
<div class="row events-list-section employee-hour-detail-section 11-27-2017">
</div>
<div class="row events-list-section employee-hour-detail-section 11-28-2017">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes you can, see the duplicate I linked to. Note that for this to work the individual classes within the `class` attributes *must* be in the exact same order on the different elements.

Comment: My divs are not integers. they are dates.

Comment: what about 12-31-2017 and 01-01-2018?

Comment: Then put the year first.

Comment: The thing is that I do not have the access of that code. But that's why I want to sort is according to the date as in the given format. Is that possible or not? Please open my question since this is an issue for me.

Comment: I added an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work you need to know the exact date value. Doing this in a class is possible, but it will be brittle and ugly code.

Instead I'd suggest putting the date in to a `data` variable in your HTML which you can then sort by comparing the values in a `sort()` handler, like this:

```js
$('.events-list-section').sort(function(a, b) {
  var aDate = $(a).data('date'), bDate = $(b).data('date');
  return new Date(aDate) - new Date(bDate);
}).appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row events-list-section employee-hour-detail-section" data-date="11-28-2017">11-28-2017</div>
<div class="row events-list-section employee-hour-detail-section" data-date="12-31-2017">12-31-2017</div>
<div class="row events-list-section employee-hour-detail-section" data-date="01-01-2018">01-01-2018</div>
<div class="row events-list-section employee-hour-detail-section" data-date="11-27-2017">11-27-2017</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. Just a last question. This doesn't seem to work on safari. Any ideas?